# In Emacs, what is the command to move the pointer to the location of the last edit?

Tags: emacs, command, move, point, key-bindings

What lisp config command would bind this command, if it's not already bound?

Also, If I wanted to bind C-x h, C-M-\, and , to a single C-M-\, how would this be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but do you know about `C-u C-SPC`? It "pops" the mark and takes you to where the last mark was. I find it very useful, especially since I usually only set the mark once or twice per any particular location I'm editing, so it only takes a couple of pops to go back to much older edit locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `session-jump-to-last-change` is part of [`session.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/session.el) which I typically bind to these two key sequences for convenience: <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-/</kbd> and <kbd>C-A-/</kbd>. I pick those keys because it is similar to `undo` which is bound by default to  <kbd>C-/</kbd>.

```
(autoload 'session-jump-to-last-change "session")
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-/") 'session-jump-to-last-change)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-A-/") 'session-jump-to-last-change)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default there is no command to move to the location of the last edit, but you can easily add it by using something like http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GotoLastChange - download the elisp file, put it in your load-path and bind it:

```
(autoload 'goto-last-change "goto-last-change"
   "Set point to the position of the last change." t)
;; bind to C-x C-\
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-\\") 'goto-last-change)
```

Comment: You get this basic functionality plus a lot more using [`session.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/session.el).

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time by typing <kbd>C-/</kbd> (undo last edit), then <kbd>C-f</kbd> (or any other trivial movement command), then <kbd>C-/</kbd> (redo last edit).